# How to save the response received using Retrofit?

Tags: android, retrofit2

I know this is Basic Question but I am new android. I have used Retrofit to get the response from URL so I have create POJO class and interface .
  So I get the respone from URL but dont understand how to save the response I can use that in another activity or fragment or  to assign value to edittext please help me

```
{
    "statusCode": "200",
    "statusMessage": "SUCCESS",
    "meetmeConfig": {
        "id": "bb52dc0f-29d0-4079-99c7-a07c8045a829",
        "moduleName": "MeetMe",
        "createdDate": 1523962430721,
        "configContent": {
            "trackingOptions": [
                {
                    "optionName": "Before the meet",
                    "isTimeRequired": true,
                    "trackingTime": [
                        5,
                        10,
                        15
                    ],
                    "isDeleted": false
                },
                {
                    "optionName": "After the meet",
                    "isTimeRequired": true,
                    "trackingTime": [
                        5,
                        10,
                        15
                    ],
                    "isDeleted": false
                },
                {
                    "optionName": "At the start",
                    "isTimeRequired": false,
                    "trackingTime": [],
                    "isDeleted": false
                },
                {
                    "optionName": "Never",
                    "isTimeRequired": false,
                    "trackingTime": [],
                    "isDeleted": false
                }
            ],
            "numberOfParticipants": 8,
            "mapResetTimeInterval": 30,
            "meetingTrackableTime": 3600,
            "addressTypes": [
                "Home",
                "Work"
            ],
            "transportModes": [
                "Walking",
                "Driving"
            ],
            "gender": [
                "Male",
                "Female",
                "Trans-Female",
                "Bi-Gender",
                "Non-Binary",
                "Gender nonconfirming",
                "Undisclosed",
                "Rather not say"
            ],
            "toastDelayTimeForPulse": 3,
            "syncToastMaxTimeInterval": 300,
            "syncToastThirdTimeInterval": 180,
            "firstTimeInterval": 1,
            "secondTimeInterval": 2,
            "meetmeSearchContactTimeInterval": 2,
            "signupToastDelayTime": 4,
            "signupToastdelatimebysix": 6,
            "signupToastDelayMedium": 5,
            "profileToastDelayTime": 4,
            "profileToastDelatimebysix": 6,
            "languages": [
                "English",
                "Spanish",
                "Marathi",
                "Hindi",
                "Bengali",
                "French",
                "Arabic",
                "German",
                "Italian",
                "Dutch",
                "Japanese",
                "Russia",
                "Korean"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Either put your data in shared preferences or sqlite.

Comment: use Singleton class

Comment: can you share a example of sigleton class

Comment: if bulk data have than use Sqlite and access the data over the app.

Comment: I have used Shared preference to save the JSON response ,response contain multiple Arraylist from that I want a single arrayList .How can I do that .

Comment: I have update the question

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you mean by saving and sharing to activity or fragment:

1. If you want to save your data permenantly, I suggest looking at Room Persistence.

You can look at this link that explains a very good way to use Retrofit and Room:

https://proandroiddev.com/the-missing-google-sample-of-android-architecture-components-guide-c7d6e7306b8f

You can look at this link for a simple Room tutorial:
https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/making-a-notes-app-using-room-database

2. If you just want to pass the data to an activity, you can save the result in variables and pass them in Intent.
3. If you want to save small variables and don't want to create a Database, you can use SharedPreferences for saving data.

Answer (score 0):

Try Room Persistence Library by google
//https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-room-with-a-view/

```
Call<YourPojo> apiCall = yourinterface.method(
    Param1,
    Param2
);

 apiCall.enqueue(new Callback<YourPojo>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<YourPojo> yourPojo, Response<BPResponse> response) {
        //here you can save response to Database/SharedPreferences etc

    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<YourPojo> yourPojo, Throwable t) {

    }
});
```

Comment: So, your answer suggests using Room Persistence Library but where is the code which shows _How to use Room Persistence Library?_ Linking to external resources is good but you need to post atleast main parts of the code here. If the linked source goes offline or unavailable we should be able to see it here IMO

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are confused to save the respones from json. So i'll give you a quick example

For an exampe :

Json response :

```
{
"STATUS": "FAILED",
"MESSAGE": "PLEASE LOGIN"
}
```

Pojo Class :

```
@SerializedName("STATUS")
@Expose
private String success; //object

@SerializedName("MESSAGE")
@Expose
private String message;

public String getSuccess() {
    return success;
}

public void setSuccess(String success) {
    this.success = success;
}

public String getMessage() {
    return message;
}

public void setMessage(String message) {
    this.message = message;
}
```

How to call it or save the respone :

```
Call<yourpojo> call = youinterface.getResult();
    call.enqueue(new Callback<yourpojo>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<yourpojo> call, Response<yourpojo> response) {
            try {
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    String status = response.body().getStatus();
        String message = response.body().getMessage();
                } else {
                    try {
                        Converter<ResponseBody, ApiError> converter = ApiHandler.getApi(getActivity()).responseBodyConverter(ApiError.class, (java.lang.annotation.Annotation[]) new Annotation[0]);
                        ApiError error = converter.convert(response.errorBody());
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), response.errorBody().string(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<yourpojo> call, Throwable t) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), t.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

I hope my example will help you out! Contact me if you have a question

Comment: In your example  if i want to use the recevied response(message) in another activity or if assign the some value to edittext                                                   
  how can i do that ?

Comment: you can save it in SharedPreferenceManager class. Please search it if you never tried it.